# Creating a code that starts with the number 1 and then displays the result of half the previous number

Tags: python

Write Python code that starts with the number 1 and then displays the result of halving the previous number until the result is less than 0.001.

The expected output should be: 1.0 0.5 0.25 0.125 0.0625 0.03125 0.015625 0.0078125 0.00390625 0.001953125

I've tried a couple different things , still learning how to code ,
but I cant figure out what I am missing

```
basenum = 1.000
endnum = 0.001
print(basenum)
while basenum > endnum:
    basenum /=2
    print(basenum)
```

how would I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you added an extra `/` in the line `basenum //=2`.
This should instead be `basenum /= 2`.

In Python, `/=` is similar to `+=`, `-=`, and `*=`, where it modifies the variable on the left by the number on the right, in this case through divison.

Instead, `//=` is floor division.  This is why you got the result of `1` and then `0`, as `1` divide `2` is 0.5, which is then floored to 0.

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp).

Answer (score 0):

[Attaching python codes and the desired output click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/623ul.png)

```py
num = 1.000
endnum = 0.001
print(num)
while num > endnum:
    num /=2
    print(num)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The `//` operator is floor division so `1.000 // 2` is equal to `0`. Use regular division instead (`basenum / 2`).

Using `//` operator:
[image]

Using `/` operator:
[image]

Comment: Avoid posting code and console output in screenshots; instead paste it in a code block

Comment: post code not images